# Delphi x Android Intents

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent

I need help with my app. This app run in Sunmi Device and I would like a payment integration (another app).

My code for send intent its ok. But I need to receive an intent response.

Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="pay-response"
        android:scheme="scheme_return" />
</intent-filter>
```

Send intent:

```
uri :='payment-app://pay?return_scheme=scheme_return&amount=' + valorTotal + '&transaction_type=debit';

  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW, TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(TIdURI.URLEncode(uri))));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```

In my "uri" I have a **return_scheme** parameter. If the value of the parameter is the same as the manifest **android:scheme="scheme_return"**, the payment is finished in the payment app, when my app return, the app is crashed (frozen).
If I change **return_scheme** parameter of any other value, when finished payment, my app open correctly.

I think the app is waiting on an intent response.
But how to get this answer?

--------EDIT---------

My code for receive intent:

```
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AppEventService: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, AppEventService) then
    AppEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent);

  MainActivity.registerIntentAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageReceivedNotification, HandleActivityMessage);
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  if M is TMessageReceivedNotification then
    HandleIntentAction(TMessageReceivedNotification(M).Value);
end;

function TForm1.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
var
  StartupIntent: JIntent;
begin
  Result := False;
  if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.BecameActive then
  begin
    StartupIntent := MainActivity.getIntent;
    if StartupIntent <> nil then
      HandleIntentAction(StartupIntent);
  end;
end;

function TForm1.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var
  Extras: JBundle;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Data <> nil then
  begin
    Memo1.ClearContent;
    Extras := Data.getExtras;
    if Extras <> nil then
      Memo1.Text := JStringToString(Extras.getString(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT));
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

After payment is finished, i received intent in `HandleIntentAction`, but always is `nil`.
SDK Reference (in Kotlin): https://sdkandroid.stone.com.br/reference/pagamento-deeplink

Comment: Your intent filter does not seem to match your code. Please see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking). Also, you need to include the code you are using to handle the incoming intent, since you've indicated that is when the crash occurs.

Comment: @DaveNottage Exactly this. The filters are ok, I follow documentation of payment app provider. I need get response of intent, but I don't know.

Comment: You don't know what, exactly? Is the payment app provider's documentation public?

Comment: Please provide more code. like your activity that this <intent-filter> is belong to

Comment: @dalmif I updated my question with more informations. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DaveNottage I updated my question with more informations. Thanks for your help

Comment: The [manifest for their test app](https://github.com/stone-payments/pos-android-deeplink-demo/blob/master/native/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) has: `android:scheme="@string/scheme_return"`. The `@string` means the value is loaded from `strings.xml`, and [theirs](https://github.com/stone-payments/pos-android-deeplink-demo/blob/master/native/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml) shows a value of `deeplinktest`, so you'll need to (at least) change your manifest to read: `android:scheme="deeplinktest"`

Comment: Also going by the documentation, there is no EXTRA_TEXT in the intent bundle. It has key names like `cardholder_name`, `itk` etc. It might pay to do the same as their test code, i.e. dump `intent.data.toString()`, so you can see exactly what it is returning

Comment: @DaveNottage I Inserted "deeplinktest" in the manifest. `data.getDataString` return empty and `data.toString` return `'Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.embarcadero.ReceiveIntent/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity }'`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take into consideration the following steps:

1. When you start the payment activity, use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity:

```java
int PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
String uri = "payment-app://pay?return_scheme=scheme_return&amount=" + valorTotal + "&transaction_type=debit";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivityForResult(intent, PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE); <--- Aqui
```

2. If possible, make sure that the payment app sends back the result correctly. It should set the result using setResult and call finish to close its activity:

```java
// In the payment app's activity that handles the payment logic
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("status", "success"); // You can add any extra data if needed
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

By using startActivityForResult and implementing onActivityResult, your app will be able to handle the response from the payment app appropriately.
I hope this helps.

Regards,

Comment: I updated my question with more informations. Thanks for your help